# Refresh bottom navigation bar fragment from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that has `BottomNavigationView` and I use `Fragment` to display stuff when an item on the navigation bar is clicked.

In that activity I have:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navItemListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.item1:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new Fragment1()).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new Fragment2()).commit();
                return true;
            case R.id.item3:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new Fragment3()).commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};
```

In my `Fragment1`, I have an edit button that when clicked, will start another `Activity` that acts as a `Dialog` (set theme in manifest). In that activity I only have a `TextView` and `Button` for editing the text in my `item1` fragment.

In my Edit Activity I have:

```
private class ButtonClicked implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.btnEdit:

                UpdateText();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(new Fragment1()).attach(new Fragment1()).commit();
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.btnCancel:
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The text updates, but the detach attach doesn't seem to work and I still have to click on another item on my bottom navigation bar to see the edited text. How can I do it so when the `Button` is clicked, the `Activity` will close, and I can see my `TextView` in my `Fragment` already updated?

Comment: Why are you detaching a newly created `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of detaching and reattaching a new fragment from your Edit Activity, you could keep the active one and just notify it in several ways.

1) Start your Edit Activity with startActivityForResult() and make your edit activity return a result to the caller before finish. (The caller would be the Activity that encapsulates the fragment, but the callback can easily be propagated to the fragment inside).

2) Use LocalBroadcastManager to send a local notification from your Edit Activity and register the caller as a receiver for that notification

But other solutions are possible